# Python Curses Module preset text

Tags: python, input, python-curses

I just started using the Curses python module, and I was wondering if there was a way to preset text. E.g, when you ran the code it would print:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Cras nec sapien ut dui mattis viverra.
Nam et pharetra erat. Mauris sodales aliquam purus, ac congue urna dictum eu. 
Donec varius facilisis quam, at malesuada odio tincidunt et. Duis fermentum leo
at mi sodales sodales quis vel urna.
```

and then, you were able to edit that preset text freely. Thanks.